# Как уменьшить дочерние элементы при transfrom: scale?

Tags: html, css

Вот такой пример:

При scale блока, дочерние элементы тоже увеличиваются... Как можно оставить элементы в начальном состоянии?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(2)
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Заметил, что если не использовать `translate(50%, 50%)` (в моем проекте необходимо данное правило), то дочерние элементы увеличиваться не будут

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: scale(2)
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Comment: можно применить к дочерним элементам обратные преобразования

Comment: @Grundy, пробовал, scale(-2), например, а они еще сильнее увеличиваются

Comment: обратный в случае scale это не знак менять, а единицу разделить, то есть, если у родителя `scale(2)`, у дочернего элемента `scale(1/2) -> scale(.5)`

Comment: забавно, но порядок преобразований в свойстве transform так же влияет на отображения и `scale, translate` и `translate, scale` могут отображаться по разному

Comment: @Grundy забавно, когда удивляются разным результатам (2+5) * 2 и  2 * 2 +5

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, формально понятно, что это порядок применения, но по сравнению с другими свойствами css в которых порядок не важен выглядит странно :)

Comment: @Grundy так это потому что связано с позиционированием от левого верхнего угла. Или мы сначала умножили на два и  координаты стали в два раза больше начальных или мы сначала прибавили, а потом умножили - результат другой

Comment: @Grundy последовательность следования преобразований задает порядок умножения матриц, которыми представлены эти преобразования, что в корне меняет результат

Comment: @StrangerintheQ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998665/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-transfrom-scale?noredirect=1#comment1688886_998665 :)

Comment: @Grundy да я пока писал вы початились знатно :)